# VB.Net - Check when user has clicked outside Form but not minimised

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, events

I'm trying to create a copy-pasting utility in VB.NET forms, where I select text from anywhere, drag it to a textbox, and it is automatically copied to the clipboard as plaintext. I want it set up so that when the window is open and I click off it, this line is executed:

```
CopyBox.SelectAll()
```

But none of the events I've tried worked. I've tried using MyBase.LostFocus, MyBase.Leave, MyBase.Deactivate, but none of them are fired when I click outside the form. They work if I minimise the form, but that's not helpful. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the [drag and drop events](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2007/07/07/basic-drag-and-drop-in-winforms/)?

Comment: I just tried using .DragOver and .DragEnter for the textbox, but neither of them fired when I attempted to drag text into the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

In a mouse Keydown event, check the location of the cursor relative to the form. If it is outside, just execute the desired function.

as per my comment

```
Declare Auto Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Short

While True
  If GetAsyncKeyState(1) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("click")
  End If
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150) 
End While
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify that without knowing the exact bounds of the Form, e.g. "If CursorPosition is OutsideOfForm" or do I need to use the x and y coordinates and the size of the form?

Comment: You can also try setting the Capture property of the form. Set this to true and, it will cause that form to receive mouse events even if the mouse is outside of the form as long as no other control has focus.  I think the lostfocus event will fire this way.

Comment: Sounds good, though I'm not sure quite how to do it. I tried using MyBase.MouseDown, but that only works if the Mouse is over the Form, which defeats the point.

Comment: you can use GetAsyncKeyState to detect clicks outside of the form.   I edited my response with a snippet of code

Comment: Again, good idea, but I don't know how to implement it. I've only used GetAsyncKeyState in Console and I have no idea how to translate it or where to use it in Forms.

Comment: Just add it to your form class.  Put whatever event/function you want in the true part of the if block.   You may need to implement a timer for this.  Ill see if i can come up with a good example but give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Deactivate event of the 'form' itself instead of the text control?

Comment: Yeah. I just tried it again, it's weird, it only works in Debug. When I put a breakpoint in, click inside the textbox, then click outside the form, the event fires and everything works smoothly. Without a breakpoint, I click inside the textbox, click outside the form and then nada.